# Roundcube Out-of-Office strange characters always show up

Tags: roundcube

I've been trying to solve this issue for a week with no success.

Whenever I try to create an out-of-office message in Roundcube by logging in to the Webmail, then heading over the Settings page, and then clicking the Out of Office menu.
[image: Out-of-office page]

Note that when saved it's always stored like this in the `sievefilter.sieve` file:

```
 # Sieve Filter^M
 ^M
 require ["vacation"];^M
 # rule:[Out of Office]^M
 if true^M
 {^M
     vacation :addresses "someone@email.com" :subject "Out of office" text:^M
 Hi,

 My apologies, I'm out of office until next Sunday. I'll reply to your email once I'm online.

 Regards,

 Someone^M
 .^M
 ;^M
 }^M
```

FYI, there's always an extra `^M` at each line.

I have traced the source codes line by line, but I couldn't find any possible root cause.

Any clue on what's going on?

Comment: how do you edit the files? it looks for me, that these files could been touched in dos format instead of unix - in that case `dos2unix` could help you

Comment: @djdomi, my apologies for the confusion. I have added more details to clarify it. I'm not sure, somehow there's something wrong when the app stores the message into the file.

Comment: but in the end, its a file and this file might have dos instead unix format, just try to copy it to a save place, use dos2unix and replace that file

Comment: Is this implemented via some unofficial RoundCube plugin? Which one? (There is no "out of office" plugin amongst [standard](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/tree/master/plugins) plugins.)